Is there a Kubernetes equivalent to Docker Compose Extensions in YAML?
I am trying to use YAML's anchors & aliases for my Kubernetes configurations.
I have this working (with extraneous configurations removed for brevity):
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code
            volumeClaimTemplate: &volume_claim_template_configurations
              spec:
                resources:
                  requests:
                    storage: 5Gi
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code
            volumeClaimTemplate: *volume_claim_template_configurations

However, I would like to define the anchor outside of the actual configurations like so:
# Docker allows extension keywords like `x-volumeClaimTemplateDefintion` to be defined
volumeClaimTemplateDefinition: &volume_claim_template_configurations
  spec:
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 5Gi

apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code
            volumeClaimTemplate: *volume_claim_template_configurations
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code
            volumeClaimTemplate: *volume_claim_template_configurations

Docker Compose has a feature called extensions that allows for this because it ignores any keys that start with x-anykey: https://docs.docker.com/reference/compose-file/extension/
Kubernetes will complain that volumeClaimTemplateDefinition is not a valid keyword.
Does Kubernetes have something equivalent to Docker Compose's Extensions so I can define the repetitive configurations outside of the first instance that the configuration is used?
Thank you for your time and guidance 

A templating tool like Helm or Carvel's ytt would be a more typical approach to this setup.  YAML anchors have some obvious limitations, including that they can't be used across files, they can't be parameterized, and they can't be used inside strings.

@DavidMaze, I agree Helm or equivalent would be the better approach.  Unfortunately, those tools aren't available in my situation.  If there's no native YAML way of doing things, then I can take that back for discussion.  For now, I'm hoping there's a native YAML way of doing this and I can avoid introducing another tool into the toolchain.  Thanks again for the suggestion.
